# Why won't the cultist spawn?

Tags: ps3, terraria-console

I killed Golem, so I went to check my dungeon to defeat the lunatic cultist and when I get there I found nothing. Is there a glitch on PS3?

Answer (score 2):

Terraria on the console is only at [version 1.2.3](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_version). Since the [Lunar Bosses were only introduced in 1.3](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunar_Events), the game on console currently does not have this content.